# Ruby Faker library is not working for some locales

Tags: ruby, rubygems, locale, rails-i18n, faker

I am using ruby faker gem to be able to generate fake data. I need the generated data to be in greek. For some reason, I can generate data in english and russian, but not greek:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'faker'

irb(main):082:0* puts Faker::Name.name
Dr. Assunta Wiegand

irb(main):083:0> Faker::Config.locale = :ru
=> :ru
irb(main):084:0> puts Faker::Name.name
Новикова Валентина
=> nil

irb(main):086:0> Faker::Config.locale = :gr
=> :gr
irb(main):087:0> puts Faker::Name.name
I18n::InvalidLocale: :gr is not a valid locale
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!'

irb(main):090:0> Faker::Config.locale = :el
=> :el
irb(main):091:0> puts Faker::Name.name
I18n::InvalidLocale: :el is not a valid locale
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple: Nobody has written a greek localisation for Faker yet.
You can look in the repository to see the locales:

https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/master/lib/locales

No `gr.yml` yet.
But it is your chance to become immortal, by writting the greek localisation.